# Error while Installing Talend v7.0.1 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, installation, talend

I am trying to install Talend Open Studio for Data Integration v7.0.1 on a Windows 10 (64 bit) machine and I get error as a log file in my configuration folder.

My Java version is 10.0.1.

ERROR is two log files long. Here's the snippet from first file
`eclipse.buildId=unknown`
`java.version=10.0.1`
`java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.`
`BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US`
`Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64`

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2018-04-27 11:19:37.120`
`!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR`
`!STACK 0`
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.ds [4]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.event; version="1.0.0"

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)`
```

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx 4 0 2018-04-27 11:19:41.576`
`!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR`
`!STACK 0`
`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:` `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx [334]`
  `Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: eclipse.platform; filter:="(osgi.os=macosx)"`

```
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)`
`at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)`
```

Let me know if you would like to share the log files too

Comment: Java 10 is pretty new. Are you sure this third-party works with it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the Java version you have installed. Talend 7.0.1 (and v6) only supports Java 8.

From Talend documentation:
[image]

Comment: Great ! Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem ;)