# I can't use Talend Open Studio Big Data

Tags: bigdata, talend

My Talend Open Studio for Big Data is not executing.
I already installed JDK 10.0.

At first this is the initial screen:

[image: Initial Screen]

Right after that here is the Error message

[image: Image Error]

Then it will create a logfile:

[image: Log]

Comment: Talend doesn't support Java 10; check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068701/error-while-installing-talend-v7-0-1-on-windows-10-machine/50069888#50069888

Comment: Thank you so much!